# How can I save a checkboxList from EditItemTemplate in ASP.NET to database?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, checkboxlist

I have a gridView and I want to change `ItemTemplate` to `CheckBoxList` when I click on the `Edit` button.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"  
     DataKeyNames="ID" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" 
      OnRowEditing="GridView1_RowEditing" OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound" >
    <Columns>
        <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True"/>

        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="LeagueExpert" SortExpression="LeagueExpert">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBoxList ID="CheckBoxList1" runat="server" 
                     DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" 
                     DataTextField="League_Name" DataValueField="League_Name"
                     style="vertical-align: middle"></asp:CheckBoxList>      
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label125" class="form-control" runat="server" 
                     onCheckedChanged="onChackedChange"  
                     Text='<%# Bind("LeagueExpert") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
```

The result:

[image]

Now I want to save; if I checked 1 and 2 option from CheckboxList, I want to save this in this format: 1,2.

Thanks

Comment: Have a look at [this tutorial](http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial/editing-data-using-asp-net-gridview-control). It covers all the basics of GridView editing and updating.

Comment: @VDWWD i dont see anything there abuot CheckboxList

Comment: That does not matter. A Control is a Control. You can access them all the same way if you follow that tutorial.